# Where to find ag-grid version wise features

Tags: ag-grid

I'm new to ag-grid.. I want to know whether ag-grid Master/ Detail grid is supported in ag-grid 5.1.0 which is used in existing frame work.. How can I get these details (version wise features).

Thanks

> I found master detail view feature works over v5.3.0 by going through
>   ag-grid.js , which was a pain :( . I hope there should be a version
>   vise api !

Answer (score 2):

They have a [ChangeLog](https://www.ag-grid.com/change-log/changeLogIndex.php?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0). Just a little searching after that should help you find what you need

Comment: Yes, I found this . It supports up to some extend since its a change log. It would be more supportive if they had version vise API's, as a suggestion !, like in java.... WDT?